# Converting rdd to dataframe: AttributeError: 'RDD' object has no attribute 'toDF'

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

```
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext

conf = SparkConf().setAppName("myApp").setMaster("local")
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)

a = sc.parallelize([[1, "a"], [2, "b"], [3, "c"], [4, "d"], [5, "e"]]).toDF(['ind', "state"])

a.show()
```

Results in:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/ktemlyakov/messing_around/SparkStuff/mock_maersk_data.py", line 7, in <module>
    a = sc.parallelize([[1, "a"], [2, "b"], [3, "c"], [4, "d"], [5, "e"]]).toDF(['ind', "state"])
AttributeError: 'RDD' object has no attribute 'toDF'
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 7):

`sqlContext` is missing; it needs to be created. The following code works:

```
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
from pyspark import sql

conf = SparkConf().setAppName("myFirstApp").setMaster("local")
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
sqlContext = sql.SQLContext(sc)

a = sc.parallelize([[1, "a"], [2, "b"], [3, "c"], [4, "d"], [5, "e"]]).toDF(['ind', "state"])

a.show()
```

**Edit:**

In Spark 2.0, the above can be achieved with:

```
from pyspark import SparkConf
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder.master("local").config(conf=SparkConf()).getOrCreate()

a = spark.createDataFrame([[1, "a"], [2, "b"], [3, "c"], [4, "d"], [5, "e"]], ['ind', "state"])
a.show()
```

Answer (score -2):

u can directly do this

```
a_df = a.toDF()
type(a_df)
```